# Java Relative path with URI

Tags: java, uri

The code below reads a local file.

```
final String filepath= "my/path/to/file.txt";

try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filepath))){
    System.out.println("First line : "+reader.readLine());
}
```

However, I want the exact equivalent but using URI. So my new code is as follow:

```
final String filepath= "file:///my/path/to/file.txt";

try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(new URI(filepath)))){
    System.out.println("First line : "+reader.readLine());
}
```

And this is working well when `filepath` is an absolute path. But I want this to work even with a relative path (like in the first code).

How can I do that ?

EDIT :

The solution I use is to use 'normal' path when I need local relative path, and URI in other cases (absolute path or remote).

So my code is like that :

```
final String filepath= "my/path/to/file.txt"; // or "file:///my/path/to/file.txt";
final URI uri = new URI(filepath);
final Path path;

if(uri.getScheme()!=null) {
    path = Paths.get(uri);
}else {
    path = Paths.get(filepath);
}

try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)){
    System.out.println("First line : "+reader.readLine());
}
```

It's not really pretty but the work is done. If there is a better solution I am still open to it.

Comment: remove one slash

Comment: `Files.newBufferedReader(Path path)`, right ? How did you use `URI` instead ?

Comment: You are right, I forgot the `Paths.get()` part. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this which is redundant:

```
        URI uri = URI.create("file://" + Paths.get("my/path/to/file.txt").toAbsolutePath());

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(uri))){
        System.out.println("First line : "+reader.readLine());
    }
```

If you can, share us the case you need an URI to point on a relative path file.